# regex to match repetitive text divided by hash character that can repeat multiple times in multi line string

Tags: c#, regex

i have the following regex i'm using with C#

```
^.*(#\w+?#.+?#.+?#.+?#.+?:).*$
```

I need to be able to extract the last occurrence of a specifically formatted string within a multi line string

The format can be :

```
#test12345-abc#slkjs3234-df#slkj23423#slkjdj2343:{asdf9230-232_jk233}
```

or

```
#test12345-abc#slkjs3234-df#slkj23423#slkjdj2343:
```

and could have the format appear 1 or more times and back to back see examples below:

Example 1:

```
jlkjlkjlkjlkj
lkjlkjlj lkjlkj  #test12345-abc#slkjs3234-df#slkj23423#slkjdj2343:{asdf9230-232_jk233}  lkjlj
slkjlj
```

Example 2:

```
jlkjlkjlkjlkj
lkjlkjlj lkjlkj #test12345-abc#slkjs3234-df#slkj23423#l23lkj22:{asdf9230-232_jk233} #test12345-abc#slkjs3234-df#slkj23423#Other:{asdf9230-232_jk233}  lkjlj
slkjlj
```

Example 3:

```
jlkjlkjlkjlkj
lkjlkjlj lkjlkj  #test12345-abc#slkjs3234-df#slkj23423#slkjdj2343:  lkjlj
slkjlj
```

Example 4:

```
jlkjlkjlkjlkj
lkjlkjlj lkjlkj #test12345-abc#slkjs3234-df#slkj23423#l23lkj22: #test12345-abc#slkjs3234-df#slkj23423#Other:  lkjlj
slkjlj
```

i'm struggling to find the proper regex that would look for both the examples and in the different positions in the examples ?? thanks

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand the problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This works  [here](https://regexr.com/)   /#.*}/g   To recreate, copy your examples into the text field and then put the regex in at the top.

Comment: Try `var result = Regex.Match(text, @"(?:#\w+(?:-\w+)?)+:{[\w-]+}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)?.Value;`

Comment: thx @Wiktor that worked. i would not find my last 2 examples that did not have the  {..} text at the end after :, but that's fine i really appreciate it, i'll just take out the {[\w-]+} and then it works for those, i can just check for both ;) of i you have another idea for a single regex to handle both :) otherwise i don't want to take up more of your time, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"(?:#\w+(?:-\w+)?)+(?::{[\w-]+})?", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)?.Value;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0yt575/1). Note that the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option makes the regex engine search for a match from the end of the string, so you get the last match if there are more than one.

**Details**

- `(?:#\w+(?:-\w+)?)+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `#` - a `#` char
  - `\w+` - one or more word chars (letters, digits, underscores)
  - `(?:-\w+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `-` and then 1+ word chars
- `(?::{[\w-]+})?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `:` - a colon
  - `{[\w-]+}` - a `{` char, then one or more letters, digits, underscores or hyphens and then a `}` char.